# Spark read.csv does not ignore separator character inside quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark 2.4 in order to read a simple csv file into a dataframe, and then doing a `show()` to the console.
Here is the csv in question, and the code I run:

CSV:

```
A|B|C
AAAA|BBBB|CCCC
A"||114|WWWW|CC|BBBBB|AAAF||"ZZZZ FFFF
"||114|WWWW|CC|BBBBB|AAAF||"ZZZZ FFFF
A"||114|WWWW|CC|BBBBB|AAAF||"ZZZZ FFFF | FFF | GGGG
```

Code:

```
>>> df_am_event =  
spark.read.option('delimiter','|').option('quote','"').option('header','true').csv('testDS')
>>> df_am_event.show()
+--------------------+----+----+
|                   A|   B|   C|
+--------------------+----+----+
|                AAAA|BBBB|CCCC|
|                  A"|null| 114|
|"||114|WWWW|CC|BB...|null|null|
|                  A"|null| 114|
+--------------------+----+----+
```

The issue here, is that I want to see the same behavior as in the third record, for the second and fourth record. That is, any separator between quotes should be ignored.

But what happens in practice, is that if I add anything in front of the quotes, the separator is no longer ignored.

What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should read it as a text file and then clean it first. The problem is your csv has 2 different separators and neither of them are commas. Once you read the file as text, strip all lines with the `"` or split the elements, then you can split on your separator `|` and then once you have necessary elements, convert `toDF`

Comment: try without `.option('quote','"')`

Comment: @Lamanus , it shows the exact same behavior without that option

Comment: @pissall , what do you mean by 2 different seperators? I only have one separator: `|` .  I don't want to ignore the quotes, I want the "separator" characters inside the quotes to be interpreted as plain text, and not as a separator

Comment: Well, the strings are too mixed and there is no way to select a quote for the records `AAAA`, `A"...`, `"...`. But you need quote to escape the delimiter. AFAI tried, it is impossible.

Comment: you use quotes in csv reader to enclose the whole field, not the part of the field. For your task, read the file into one column df and then use regex to split the fields.